# Magento Error upon Overriding in local folder

Tags: magento

This is the error message:
Fatal error: Call to a member function initForm() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Edit\Tabs.php on line 58

I copy this file:
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Edit\Accounts.php
to:
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\My_Project\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Edit\Tab\Accounts.php

then edit only this function:

```
<?php

class My_Project_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account
{

    public function initForm()
    {   
        Mage::log('Debug1: _initForm was called',null,'globe.log');

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('_account');
        $form->setFieldNameSuffix('account');

        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');

        /* @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
        $customerForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
        $customerForm->setEntity($customer)
            ->setFormCode('adminhtml_customer')
            ->initDefaultValues();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset',
            array('legend'=>Mage::helper('customer')->__('Account Information'))
        );

        $attributes = $customerForm->getAttributes();

        //Start of edit//
        //Remove the Un-needed labels from the Customer Information Form
        //These are the codes that I added:

        unset($attributes['prefix']);
        unset($attributes['firstname']);
        unset($attributes['middlename']);
        unset($attributes['lastname']);
        unset($attributes['suffix']);
        unset($attributes['taxvat']);
        unset($attributes['dob']);
        unset($attributes['gender']);

        //End of edit//

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $attribute->unsIsVisible();
        }
        $this->_setFieldset($attributes, $fieldset);

        /**Usual codes continues here**/
```

this are the codes on line 56-60 of Tabs.php

```
$this->addTab('account', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Account Information'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_account')->initForm()->toHtml(),
        'active'    => Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId() ? false : true
    ));
```

What I want to do here is to remove the names, zip, country, gender, etc, in Account Information Form, only the email will remain.

If I do all of this in the Core files, It all went well but If I try to override this and save it in local folder, this error arises.

P.S. I also add the config.xml in my local, and add a xml in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\etc\modules named My_Project_Adminhtml.xml

Thanks In Advance for anyone that will help.

this is my config.xml save on C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\My_Project\Adminhtml\etc

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Project_Adminhtml>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </My_Project_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_edit_tab_account>
                        My_Project_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account
                    </customer_edit_tab_account>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

this is my module xml save on .../app/etc/modules folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Project_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Project_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: is My_Project_Adminhtml an example, or the actual value you are attempting to use? You shouldn't use an underscore in the namespace section otherwise it will expect the path to all your classes to be My\Project\Adminhtml

Comment: its just an example, the value is really just 1 word like Planet_Adminhtml... sorry to mislead you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your config file is layout out the same as this, you will probably need to remove the whitespace surrounding the class name so that it is the only thing in the node.

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
        <customer_edit_tab_account>My_Project_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account</customer_edit_tab_account>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Wow! That's it. This is solved! Thank you very much. I'm new to magento and a beginner and XML, a newbie error I guess... Thank you very much again :D

Comment: It's easily done, most places in the xml the whitespace doesn't matter, just happens that it does in this case.

Comment: @Cags I am also having the same fatal error. Where is this file located exactly? Please specify. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all of your XML files are correct XML, I had exactly the same thing occur 2 days ago, because I had misspelled a closing tag. If this is causing the error, you will something like the following in your system.log

```
2012-01-23T04:40:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 56: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch:
```

Comment: I added the config.xml and My_Project_Adminhtml.xml for your reference... I am really hopeless with this one... :-(